# Windows puts extra slash in git remote repository path

Tags: windows, git

In Windows, after running

```
git remote show origin
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: '/home/git/repositories//username/git-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

There's an extra slash before username, why would that be?

This is the repo config: http://pastebin.com/5Mxr74zj

Comment: Difficult to tell without knowing what command you’re trying to run.

Comment: What is in the `.git/config` for the repo?

Comment: Just for reference, on *nix systems such an extra slash would not be a problem--it would be silently ignored (i.e. `//` means `/`).  Maybe Windows doesn't work like that but Git assumes it would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading my version of GitLab from 5.0 to 5.1